# Should I use autobox in Perl?

Tags: perl

For those unaware of Perl's [`autobox`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/autobox), it is a module that gives you methods on built in primitives, and lets you even override them.

```
# primitives
'a string'->toupper();
10->to(1); # returns [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

# Arrays, array refs
[qw(A B C D E)]->for_each( sub { ... } );
@array->length()

# Hashes, hash refs
{ key => 'value', key2 => 'value2' }->values()
%hash->keys()

# Even specify your own base class...
use autobox SCALAR => 'Foo';
```

It overall makes methods on built in types feel more like objects, simplifying some tasks and making others seem more obvious.

However...

the [`autobox`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/autobox) docs say that there's [performance penalties](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/autobox#Performance), some more than simply calling the method on the object, much more than the standard syntax.  [And then, there's a few caveats about its use in `eval`s (specifically, string evals) that might, in some circumstances, cause issues.](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/autobox#eval_EXPR)  It also looks like it doesn't come standard with many Perl distros.

Is it ever really worth it to use autobox?

Comment: It is pretty cool, but part of me can't help but thing "If I wanted to use Ruby..."

Comment: I understand why Java and C# do autoboxing: Collections only operate on objects using specific methods inherited from the base Object class (possibly overridden), so primitive types are boxed to their object types before stuffed in a collection.  Perl doesn't have anything like this, so why box primitives in objects?

Comment: 'a string'->toupper(); looks pretty pythony to me.

Comment: I think the reason people see similarities with other languages is that it's really object-oriented, and that's common across a lot of languages.  You might as well say it's "C#-ey" too; the same kind of thing works in that language too:  `"My string".ToUpper();` works by itself, and with extension methods, you can have almost the exact same syntax.

Comment: It's also very Perl6y to `'Hello world'.say`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, did you ever wish there were a module that did what [autobox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autobox) does before you found out about [autobox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autobox)?

If the answer is 'yes', then you should use it. You might also want to contribute to its development by filing bug reports and fixing them if you get the opportunity.

Unfortunately, I fall into the camp of 'cool, but ...' so I cannot offer you any more insight.

Comment: Agreed. It's pretty cool, and some of those functions look neat (the `sub { ... }->curry()` part looks interesting), but I'd like to see some documentation and some functions, rather than just the ability to autobox literals. It looks like a cool toy, not a powerful tool. That may change in the future, but if it changes it will be by solidifying the API.

Answer (score 6):

Horses for courses!   However reading a chain from left to right is often easier to grok IMHO:

```
say sort grep /\w/, map { chr } 0 .. 255;
```

While shorter below does flow nicer:

```
say [ 0..255 ]->map( sub { chr } )->grep( sub { m/\w/ } )->sort->join('');
```

ref: [snippet from Hacker News comments](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=389219)

/I3az/

Comment: I don't think the anonymous subroutine in `map { chr } 0 .. 255` is necessary - you can do `map chr, 0 .. 255` (of course, you may just like it better the first way, which is perfectly valid). I don't know if you can do that with the autobox methods, though. If you can't do it now, it should be a bug report.

Comment: The two lines come from Hacker News comments which I just pasted down (though the autobox version was my comment!)

Comment: re: autobox / bug report: Its not a bug because it needs to be a block (ie. anon sub) because otherwise the expression would be evaluated in the wrong place ;-( Perhaps one day PerlX::MethodCallWithBlock will make the necessary sugar ...->map(){ chr }->grep(){ m/w/ }->sort... perhaps? Perhaps even parentheses can be dropped!

Answer (score 5):

I use autobox for:

```
$c->login($c->req->{params}->hslice([qw/username password/])
```

This ends up taking an arbitrary hash and reduces it to `{ username => <whatever>, password => <whatever> }`.  Normally a lot of code.  One symbol with Moose::Autobox.

Comment: There's a distinction between hslice, which is a nice function, and autobox's main purpose which provides the glue to call it that way.  What would be wrong with $c->login(hslice($c->req->{params}, [qw/username password/]) ?

Comment: Isn't that the same as `$c->login(map {$_ => $c->req->{params}->{$_}} qw/username password/);`?

Comment: Yes. But Jonathan's point stands: the function he's using is certainly tidier code than that.

Comment: `$c->login(do { my $p = $c->req->{params}; map { $_ => $p->{$_} } qw/username password/})`