# How can I call methods on Perl scalars?

Tags: perl, overloading, scalar

I saw some code that called methods on scalars (numbers), something like:

```
print 42->is_odd
```

What do you have to overload so that you can achieve this sort of "functionality" in your code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you referring to [autobox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autobox)?  See also [Should I use autobox in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521563/should-i-use-autobox-in-perl).

Comment: it's one module I noticed. another one could be `scalar::object`. I saw that `autoload` uses XS, and I noticed `scalar::object` doesn't. I'd rather be more interested in the way `scalar::object` does it's thing. I'm curious if this can be done without resorting to lower level programming.

Comment: `scalar::object` uses `overload::constant` and other `overload` magic, but it also doesn't have nearly the power `autobox` does. `autobox` works by hooking into the implementation of the `->foo()` method call operator itself.

Comment: autobox certainly is the way to go for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example using the autobox feature.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package MyInt;

sub is_odd {
  my $int = shift;
  return ($int%2);
}

package main;

use autobox INTEGER => 'MyInt';
print "42: ".42->is_odd."\n";
print "43: ".43->is_odd."\n";
print "44: ".44->is_odd."\n";
```